# does %d in String.format() work for unsigned integers also?

Tags: java

in `printf()` I remember for unsigned there is `%u`... but I can find no such `%u` in specs for `String.format()`

so if I have a large `unsigned` int then `%d` will work correctly on it?

Comment: java doesn't have unsigned integers

Comment: Java 8 has unsigned integers.

Comment: AFAIK Java 8 has an API for the common workaround for not having unsigned types.

Comment: Yes, Java 8 has Integer.toUnsignedString(). It seems they forgot to add %u.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to treat an int as if it were unsigned you can to

```
int i = ...
String s = String.format("%d", i & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
```

This effectively turns the signed int into a long, but it will be from 0 .. 2^31-1

To do the reverse you can do

```
int i = (int) Long.parseLong(s);
String s2 = String.format("%d", i & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
```

And `s2` will be the same as `s` provided it is in range.

BTW: The simplest thing to do might be to use a `long` in the first place.  Unless you are creating *a lot* of these the extra memory is trivial and the code is simpler.